# Memory game - comparing if same card

Tags: java, memory

I'm trying to create a memory game with pokemon cards. It seems to work half of the time. When two pictures are the same it does seem to work but sometimes when i click another time, it hides only one of the pictures or sometimes it hides the wrong one.
Do I need to post my whole code ? If not, here's my actionPerformed where I compare if it's the same card or not.
tableauChoisi is my array that contains the numbers of pokemons.
jbtnTout is my array of buttons

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Object src = e.getSource();
         int tamponImage = 0;
        final int temp = tamponImage;
        int tamponIndice = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < jbtnTout.length; i++) {
            final int ii = i;
            if (src == jbtnTout[i]) {
                click++;
                if (click == 1) {
                    jbtnTout[i].setIcon(icon[tableauChoisi[i]]);
                    tamponImage = (int) (tableauChoisi[i]);
                    tamponIndice = i;
                }

                if (click == 2) {
                    jbtnTout[i].setIcon(icon[tableauChoisi[i]]);
                    click = 0;
                    if (tableauChoisi[tamponImage] == tableauChoisi[i]) {

                        jbtnTout[temp]
                                .setIcon(icon[tableauChoisi[ii]]);
                        jbtnTout[ii]
                                .setIcon(icon[tableauChoisi[ii]]);
                    } else if (tableauChoisi[tamponImage] != tableauChoisi[i]) {

                        new Thread(){
                            public void run(){
                                jbtnTout[temp].setIcon(icon[0]);
                                jbtnTout[ii].setIcon(icon[0]);
                            try{
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        }catch(InterruptedException e){

                        }

                            }
                    }.start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably `temp` has a value that exceeds the size of `jbtnTout`.

Comment: No. I don't get any error but for example if i have a grid of 2 by 2 it usually puts the index 0 to icon 0. it's like if it compares it with index 0 and not the last index that was clicked. I'm really not sure

Answer (score 0):

Your `temp` variable is always 0 because it's declared `final`, that could explain why it always compares with 0 index instead of last clicked.

```
 int tamponImage = 0;
 final int temp = tamponImage;
```

Comment: Dimitri Grishin, I thought of the same thing but sadly it doesn't change the result when I changed it around.